# Adding to a Sorted Doubly LinkedList (C++)

Tags: c++

I've implemented a program that creates a sorted doubly linked list. Everything works fine except the fact that I can't seem to figure out where program is accepting the node 66 as head, and 44 (which is smaller) as the node after. Here's my add function.

```
bool SortedDoublyLinkedList<ItemType>::add(const ItemType &newEntry) {
    Node<ItemType> *newNode = new Node<ItemType>();
    newNode->setItem(newEntry);

    if (size == 0) //checks if linked list is empty -> add elements if so.
    {
        head = newNode;
        newNode->setNext(NULL);  
        newNode->setPrev(NULL);
        tail = newNode;

    }
// checks if the new node to be added is small than node that head is currently pointing to. If so, add new node before head and make it the new head of list.
    else if (newNode->getItem() < head->getItem()) { 
        head->setPrev(newNode);
        newNode->setNext(head); 
        newNode->setPrev(NULL); 
        head = newNode;

    }
// checks if new node is bigger than the tail node (or last node). If so, add new node to end of list. Then make that new node the tail (end) of list.
    else if (newNode->getItem() > tail->getItem()) { 
        tail->setNext(newNode);
        newNode->setNext(NULL);
        newNode->setPrev(tail);
        tail = newNode;
    }
// if the new node is neither of the mentioned situations, add the new node in the correct position in middle of the list. TempPtr1 acts as a ptr and the new node will be added directly in front of it.
    else { 
        Node<ItemType> *tempPtr1;
      tempPtr1 = head;



            while (newNode->getItem() > tempPtr1->getItem()) {

                tempPtr1 = tempPtr1->getNext();

            }
                newNode->setPrev(tempPtr1->getPrev());
                newNode->setNext(tempPtr1); // = tempPtr1;
                tempPtr1->getPrev()->setNext(newNode);
                tempPtr1->setPrev(newNode);
            }


    size++;

    return true;
}
```

Output:
66
44
88
88

Comment: It's not entirely clear what `head` and `tail` are here. I feel that `head->setPrev(newNode);` is suspicious just based on the nomenclature. I feel that anything named "head" probably shouldn't have a non-null "prev" member. And some comments would help to clarify your code quite a bit.

Comment: How do you add you element?what's their sequence?@Modulus

Comment: There may be 1 bug in you code.If I add 88 first,another 88 second,then in the `while(newNode->getItem() > tempPtr1->getItem())`,`tempPtr1` will be null.@Modulus

Comment: Just added some comments. @Logicrat : head->setPrev(newNode) takes the current head of list and points its previous pointer to the new smaller node.

Comment: Just realized that I should check to see if the new node is bigger than the head.. but now when I compile, the output I get is 44, and then it stops...

Comment: Stepping through the code with a debugger might show you where the problem lies., especially as you have only four data items.